# C++ ReadProcessMemory slowing my prog

Tags: c++, windows, performance, memory

i'm writing a memory scanner and it work but this part of my code is slowing the scan

```
if (ReadProcessMemory(phandle,(void*)currentAddress,&value,sizeof(value),0) != 0)
{
    if (value == searchfor)
    {
    DWORD newdatasize = sizeof(newdata);
        found += 1;
        printf(" FOUND %d at 0x%08X!", searchfor, currentAddress);
        liste[currentAddress] = searchfor;
    }
    total += 1;
}
```

How I can resolve this ?

Answer (score 2):

As @fritzone describes, `ReadProcessMemory` is very slow (compared to an in-process memory read) because of all the overhead work it must perform for each request.

Currently you are reading a single value (probably 4 or 8 bytes at most) at a time with `ReadProcessMemory`. You can improve the performance of your application by instead reading large blocks of memory (several KB or MB) at a time, to amortize the overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Reading another process's memory is not the fastest operation. MSDN says:

> Before any data transfer occurs, the system verifies that all data in the base address and memory of the specified size is accessible for read access

Then:

> ReadProcessMemory copies the data in the specified address range from the address space of the specified process into the specified buffer of the current proces

Depending where the piece of memory you try to read is placed this can take up some time. Just imagine, that it was paged out to the pagefile. Then the OS needs to re-read the data back from the pagefile, needs to put it somewhere in the process's memory, possibly needs to write something else out to the pagefile. This "messing with other process's internal stuff" feels like touching their intimate parts. Don't do it unless you really have to, and if you have to do it carefully.

Comment: Yeah but cheat engine or tools like ollydbg can do a scan in 10 seconds and I need to read memory to compare.